# Conditional probability, Baye's rule, prisoner Ural / Siberia + coat exercise

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am currently statistics and probability course. One of the questions in the textbook is following:

> A prisoner will be sent to either **Urals** or **Siberia**, but he does not
>   know where. He knows, that the probability is 0.8 that he will be sent
>   to **Siberia**. He also knows the probabilities of prisoners wearing a
>   **coat** - 0.5 in **Siberia** and 0.7 in **Urals**.
>
> When he arrives to the exile, the first person he sees is not wearing
>   a coat.
>
> 1. What is the probability he is in **Siberia**?
> 2. Given previous information, he sees another one, not wearing a **coat**. What is probability now, that he is in **Siberia**?
> 3. Would it change the probability if he saw both previous people at once?

I believe the answer for the 1. is following:

$$\mathcal P(S|\bar C)={\mathcal P(S)\times\mathcal P(\bar C|S) \over \mathcal P(\bar C)}={0.8\times0.5\over 1-(0.8\times0.5+0.2\times0.7)}=\frac{20}{23}\dot=\,0.8696$$

However, I have no idea how to move further on 2. or 3. Could you please help me? Thank You!

**EDIT**

The professor quickly responded with the solution for 2. :

$$\frac{0.8696\times0.5}{0.8596\times0.5+0.1304\times0.3}=0.9174$$
From this, I've found out that the probabilities can be "chained", and decoded the underlining formula as:

$$\mathcal P(S|\bar{C_2})=\frac{\mathcal P(S|\bar C)\times\mathcal P(\bar C|S)}{\mathcal P(S|\bar C)\times\mathcal P(\bar C|S)+\mathcal P(\bar S|\bar C)\times\mathcal P(\bar C|\bar S)}$$

However, since 0.5 is the probability for $\mathcal P(\bar C|S)$ and also for $\mathcal P(C|S)$, I need a clarification, if my decoded formula is right. Thank You.

Comment: helluva problem

Comment: Thank you @Alex, are 2. and 3. commonly part of the *helluva* problem too?

Comment: what textbook is this?

Comment: It is not exactly a standard textbook - `Apuntes de Estadística (C)2011, Sixto Sánchez Merino. Universidad de Málaga`. From what is written there, the professor wrote it himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A prisoner will be sent to either Urals or Siberia, but he does not know where. He knows, that the probability is 0.8 that he will be sent to Siberia. He also knows the probabilities of prisoners wearing a coat - 0.5 in Siberia and 0.7 in Urals.
>
> When he arrives to the exile, the first person he sees is not wearing a coat.
>
> 1. What is the probability he is in Siberia?
> 2. Given previous information, he sees another one, not wearing a coat. What is probability now, that he is in Siberia?
> 3. Would it change the probability if he saw both previous people at once?

$$\rm P(S)=\frac{0.8*0.5}{0.8*0.5+0.2*0.3}=\frac{20}{23}=0.8695\cdots$$

$$\rm P(S_2)=\frac{0.8*0.5*0.5}{0.8*0.5*0.5+0.2*0.3*0.3}=\frac{100}{109}=0.9174\cdots$$

No It won't.

---

**Edit:**

$$\rm P(S|(\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2))=\frac{P(S\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}{P(\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}$$
Now since $\rm P(S\cup U)=1$
$$\rm P(S|(\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2))=\frac{P(S\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}{P((S\cup U)\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}=\frac{P(S\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}{P((S\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)\cup(U\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2))}$$
And Now, $\rm P(S\cup U)=P(S)+P(U)-P(S\cap U)$, but $\rm P(S\cap U)=0$, So:
$$\rm P(S|(\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2))=\frac{P(S\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}{P(S\cap \bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)+P(U\cap\bar C_1\cap\bar C_2)}$$

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I have learned something from a first formula, thank you. The second formula seems good too, but the result shows 0.9174 on my calculator.

Comment: @delmadord m inor typed that has been edited

Comment: The formulas you posted are results for the 1. and 3. and I learned something from both. I have edited my question, with one addition. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @delmadord see edit.

Comment: I do not get it entirely (why $\rm P(S\cap U)=1$ and then $\rm P(S\cap U)=0$?), but I have my answer and you provided a lot of effort, so thank you :)

Comment: @delmadord $\rm P(S\cup U)=1$ since you need to go any one of those and hence your probability of going to either places is 1. similarly $\rm P(S\cap U)=0$ because you can't go to both places at the same time hence it is 0.